# How to cleanup disk after sending logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

Once logs are sent to CloudWatch using the CloudWatch client, we want to cleanup the disk. We have following 2 use cases.

1. We don't login into some of the servers. We don't need to keep the logs on disk. So cleanup can happen immediately after sending logs to Server.
2. On some servers, we want to keep logs for the last N days, after which these need to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The Cloudwatch Logs Agent is compatible with logrotate, just make sure that you use one of the supported patterns.

See: [CloudWatch Logs Agent Reference - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html#agent-faq)

Comment: I still can't find a way to delete the files (cleanup). Do you know how the Agent config looks like to remove the logs after 7 days?

Comment: The cloudwatch agent doesn't handle log cleanup. You need to use an external tool like logrotate to handle that.